# XSLT - Filter single words from text

Tags: string, xslt

I have string like below parsed by an XSLT

```
boy &quot;happy family&quot; filetype:pdf girl
```

From the above string, I need to filter out only the single words "boy" and "girl" and get another string as

```
boy girl
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Sooo.. ignoring values in quotation marks and `\w+\:\w+` values?

Comment: @Neil: Yes. Those are the possible variations that could happen in the string

Comment: do I get this right: you need to remove everything between the first and last space in text() value of a node, using XSLT? - If you can do it, I would use something JavaScript or so. XSLT is designed for manipulating XML structures, not content (values).

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 2.0 you have the `replace` function taking a regular expression so doing `replace('boy &quot;happy family&quot; filetype:pdf girl', '"[^"]*"|\w+:\w+', '')` should work. With XSLT 1.0 I would first check whether your XSLT 1.0 processor support a similar extension function

Comment: Thanks. I am using XSLT 1.0, and found that replace extension function is not supported. What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: My suggestion would be an extension function but another poster has already suggested the EXSLT replace function and your comment suggests that you can't use that either. In that case XSLT 1.0 might not be the right tool although you can check whether existing string replacement callable templates can do the job, see http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/replace.html.

Answer (score 0):

For XSLT 1.0 there's replace in the `http://exslt.org/regular-expressions` name space (see http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/replace/index.html) but as Martin pointed out your processor would need support for extensions.

```
<xsl:value-of select="{http://exslt.org/regular-expressions}replace(STRING, '&quot;.*&quot;|\w+:\w+', '')"/>
```

will give what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks @hroptatyr. What would be the alternative for XSLT 1.0, without using the extension functions?

Comment: depends on your specific environment, the link I've posted contains implementations in javascript and MSXSL.  And AFAIK there's no portable XSLT 1.0 implementation available.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution that uses tokenization provided by [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** (written itself in XSLT 1.0) and the `xxx:node-set()` extension function as provided by the XSLT 1.0 processor being used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
  <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters"
                          select="' '"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:for-each select=
       "ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*
         [not(contains(., '&quot;') or contains(.,':'))
        and
          count(preceding-sibling::*[contains(., '&quot;')]) mod 2 = 0
         ]">

        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided text, wrapped in a single top element):

```
<t>boy &quot;happy family&quot; filetype:pdf girl</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
boy girl
```

**The same correct output is produced in the case of the following, more tricky XML document**:

```
<t>boy &quot; very happy family &quot; filetype:pdf girl</t>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry, my knowledge in XSLT is pretty limited. I am thinking where to get the strSplit-to-Words.xsl file from?

Comment: @itsbalur: The home of the FXSL project is at: http://sf.net/projects/fxsl . There are separate XSLT 1.0 versions and XSLT 2.0 versions. The latest XSLT 1.0 version is at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/files/fxsl/FXSL%201.2/ . The latest XSLT 2.0 version is at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/files/FXSL%20for%20XSLT%202/FXSL%202.0/ . You may read more about FXSL either at http://fxsl.sf.net or at: http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2003/Novatchev01/EML2003Novatchev01.html  or at: http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html